# Subscript in multiple legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, subscript

To make my figure suitable for black-white printing, I mapped one variable with "shape", "lty", "color" together.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=mean, 
               shape=quality, 
               lty=quality,
               color=quality))
```

I got the figure like,
[image]
I would like to make part of legends as subscribs, with the codes:

```
labels=c(expression(Pol[(Art)]), expression(Pol['(Aca-)']), expression(Pol['(Aca-)']))
```

Unfortunately, when I put the "label" in color or shape, it makes the legend quite complex, like,

[image]

Is it possible to map "shape", "color","lty" to one varible, and set the subscript, but keep them in one set of legend?

Comment: I think you should be supplying labels as an argument to `scale_colour_discrete`, rather than as an additional aesthetic? But a reproducible example would help - we can't see what you're doing

Comment: @CalumYou, Thank you very much, `scale_*_discrete` works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To change the labels of a categorical scale, you use `scale_*_discrete(labels = ...)`. Here you just need to do that for `color`, `shape`, and `linetype`.**

You should avoid using `lty =` generally; that synonym is permitted for compatibility with base R, but it's not universally supported throughout `ggplot2`.

I changed your labels to be closer to what I think you meant (the third entry is now "Aca+" instead of a repeat of "Aca-") and to make them left-align better (by adding an invisible "+" to the first one to create the appropriate spacing).

```
lab1 <- c(expression(Pol[(Art)*phantom("+")]),
          expression(Pol['(Aca-)']), 
          expression(Pol['(Aca+)']))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, 
       aes(wt, mpg, 
           color = factor(cyl), 
           shape = factor(cyl), 
           linetype = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(se = F) +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = lab1) +
  scale_shape_discrete(labels = lab1) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(labels = lab1)
```

[image]

If you find yourself needing to repeat exact copies of a function like this, there's two workarounds:

1. Relabel the data itself - **OR** -
2. Use `purrr::invoke_map` to iterate over the functions

---

```
library(purrr)

ggplot(mtcars, 
       aes(wt, mpg, 
           color = factor(cyl), 
           shape = factor(cyl), 
           linetype = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(se = F) +
  invoke_map(list(scale_color_discrete, 
                  scale_linetype_discrete, 
                  scale_shape_discrete),
             labels = lab1)
```

---

## Update:

This approach is mostly fine, but now the `expression(...)` syntax has a superior alternative, the excellent markdown-based `{ggtext}` package: https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext

To change to this method, use a (optionally, named) vector of labels that look like this:

```r
library(ggtext)

lab1 <- c(
  `4` = "Pol<sub>(Art)</sub>",
  `6` = "Pol<sub>(Aca-)</sub>", 
  `8` = "Pol<sub>(Aca+)</sub>"
)
```

And then add this line to your theme:

```r
  ... +
  theme(
    legend..text = element_markdown()
  )
```

The advantages over the other method are that:

1. markdown syntax is a lot easier to search for help online and
2. now those labels can be stored in the actual data as a column, rather than passing them separately to each geom

You can use that new column as your aesthetic mapping [`ggplot(..., aes(color = my_new_column, linetype = my_new_column, ...)`] instead of having to pass extra labels in each layer using the `purrr::invoke` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly for me! Very appreciate your kind help :)

Comment: To do mapping from specific label values to the new labels you can use: `lab1 <- c("myTextualLabelFieldValue" = expression(my^{fancy}[label]), ... )`